# Display column name from column data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a data with following structure. I am using Entity Framework.

```
Id     fileName   date                 status
---------------------------------------------
 1     file1      12-05-2016 11:30     fail
 2     file1      12-05-2016 11:35     success
 3     file2      13-05-2016 12:01     success
 4     file2      13-05-2016 12.02     fail
 5     file1      13-05-2016           success
 6     file3      13-05-2016           fail
```

I want result like this

```
fileName       12-05-2016   13-05-2016
------------------------------------------
file1          success        sucess
file2                         fail
file3                         fail
```

Criteria - Search the data between two dates and all dates file status should be displayed in above way. For the same day same file's two entries exist, then latest status will be displayed.

I am using code first approach to get data.

this is my code at repo

```
     IQueryable<FileData> filedata=this.context.FileData;
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the class you have made for the first section, along with the relevant code you used to get the data?

Comment: Please share the code for the class and the structure. What you need to do is to Pivot the data, so checkout the details for http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I need to do this for report

Comment: @Svek. Currently i do not create any class . Please help me to build the class

Comment: @NeenuJohn -- Understood. Give me a second. I will provide you an answer, but I would recommend rewording your question to clarify your problem. **How exactly are you using Entity Framework?**

Comment: Okay.@Svek thank you.

Comment: @NeenuJohn -- how is it that `file2` is `fail` for `13-05-1026`? In addition, your dates... You have `3016` and `1026`... I don't understand how these match up in your columns.

Comment: It a mistake actually. it should 13-05-2016

Comment: @Svek . Iam waiting for your reply.

Comment: @NeenuJohn - Could you still explain why `file2` is status `fail` for `13-05-2016`?

Comment: file 2 has 2 entry in 13-05-2016  one is at 12:01. another 12:02, i need to display only the latest status that is fail. This is the logic

Answer (score 1):

I created a pivot table based on Svek code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStatus filestatus = new FileStatus();
            filestatus.Load();
            DataTable pivot = filestatus.PivotTable();
        }
    }
    public class FileStatus
    {
        public static List<FileStatus> filedata = new List<FileStatus>();

        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        public void Load()
        {
            filedata = new List<FileStatus>()
            {
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 1, filename = "file1", date = new DateTime(2016,05,12,11,30,00), status = "fail"},
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 2, filename = "file1", date = new DateTime(2016,05,12,11,35,00), status = "success"},
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 3, filename = "file2", date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,01,00), status = "success"},
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 4, filename = "file2", date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,02,00), status = "fail"},
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 5, filename = "file1", date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,30,00), status = "success"},
                new FileStatus(){ Id = 6, filename = "file3", date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,31,00), status = "fail"}
            };
        }
        public DataTable PivotTable()
        {
            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();

            DateTime[] uniqueDates = filedata.Select(x => x.date.Date).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            pivot.Columns.Add("filename", typeof(string));
            foreach (DateTime date in uniqueDates)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), typeof(string));
            }

            var groups = filedata.GroupBy(x => x.filename).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["filename"] = group.Key;

                foreach (FileStatus filestatus in group)
                {
                    newRow[filestatus.date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")] = filestatus.status;
                }
            }
            return pivot;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, here is an example class that would work

```
public class FileStatus
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a working sample that would get you the result you want, so that you can pass it onto your report template:

```
var filedata= new List<FileStatus>()
{
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 1, Filename = "file1", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,12,11,30,00), Status = "fail"},
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 2, Filename = "file1", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,12,11,35,00), Status = "success"},
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 3, Filename = "file2", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,01,00), Status = "success"},
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 4, Filename = "file2", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,02,00), Status = "fail"},
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 5, Filename = "file1", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,30,00), Status = "success"},
    new FileStatus(){ Id = 6, Filename = "file3", Date = new DateTime(2016,05,13,12,31,00), Status = "fail"}
};

//remove the above and replace it with your own:
//IQueryable<FileData> filedata = this.context.FileData;

var result = filedata.GroupBy(c => new { c.Filename, c.Date.Date }).Select(c => new
{
    Row = c.Key.Filename,
    Column = c.Key.Date,
    Value = filedata.FirstOrDefault(co => co.Id == c.Max(max => max.Id)).Status
}).OrderBy(c => c.Row).OrderBy(c => c.Column);
```

Comment: @JavierJimenezMatilla - yes. It needs to get put into a report template. I can update it to do a simple pivot, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to pay me for that, hahaha, all the example is wrong (repeats, year 1016¿?, hour with . instead of :, and without hour), I check you has written quickly...so:

```
declare @cols   nvarchar(max)
declare @query  nvarchar(max)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [id]            [int]           NULL,
    [filename]      [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
    [date]          [datetime]      NULL,
    [status]        [nvarchar](50)  NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into table_1
values
(1     ,'file1'      ,'12-05-2016 11:30:00.000'     ,'fail'),
(2     ,'file1'      ,'12-05-2016 11:35:00.000'     ,'success'),
(3     ,'file2'      ,'13-05-2016 12:01:00.000'     ,'success'),
(3     ,'file2'      ,'13-05-2016 12:02:00.000'     ,'fail'),
(4     ,'file1'      ,'13-05-2016 12:03:00.000'     ,'success'),
(5     ,'file3'      ,'13-05-2016 12:04:00.000'     ,'fail')


select t2.filename,dat, status 
    into #temp1 
   FROM
        (select filename, cast([date] as date) as dat, max([date]) as maxdat 
            from table_1 
            group by filename, cast([date] as date)
        ) t1
   INNER JOIN
    table_1 t2
        on t1.filename = t2.filename
        and t2.[date] = t1.maxdat
        and cast(t2.date as date) = t1.dat

--select * from #temp1
--after that you want pivot by date and max status for example¿?

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), datelist, 120)) 
                    from 
                    (
                    select distinct cast(dat as date) as datelist from #temp1
                    )t1

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--select @cols

set @query = 
('select filename, ' + @cols + '
   from #temp1
   pivot (
        max(status)
        for dat in (' + @cols + ')
   )p
')

print @query

exec(@query)
```

Hope this help you! $$

Comment: this example is in tsql, you can create a stored procedure for read